# Insert Errors when run from js, xampp shell worked fine with same sql

Tags: mysql, node.js, xampp

heres the sql im trying to run, when i use xampp i am able to get the responce to insert my table. but if i pass the sql into my query function i am unable to get the query to insert into my table. and i get the below error instead:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO address_tbl (address_ln_1, address_ln_2, address_town, address_county, address_postcode) VALUES ('place', '', 'Town', 'county', 'postcode');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
COMMIT;
```

using the js:

```
var query= function (sql){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if(err) throw err;
                resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

error:

```
C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO address_tbl (address_ln_1, address_ln_2, address_town, address_count' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:525:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:201:25)
    at resolve (C:\db.js:18:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.query (C:\db.js:17:12)
    at insert (C:\utl\order_model.js:16:8)
    at Order.insert (C:\utl\order_model.js:99:9)
    at utill.calculate_cart (C:\routes\orderRouter.js:65:15)
    at pm.getProducts.productlist (C:\utl\utill.js:22:9)
    at Object.getProducts (C:\utl\products_model.js:27:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax at line 1

Comment: Make sure that your table and the table fields are spelled correctly and that they take into account that it's case sensitive (small and big letters matter). Then make sure that the corresponding values match the specification of the table fields (int, string etc. etc.). Currently, all of your values are strings. Also, make sure that the table field "address_ln_2" is allowed to hold an empty string. I would probably incorporate some sort of NULL logic for this.

Comment: If you also have more fields in your table that you don't address in your SQL function, then make sure that they take NULL values by default, or assign a NULL value to them, and make sure that they are allowed to contain a NULL value in the first place.

Comment: Also looks like you have a typo in the error?. "address_count" should be "address_county"? Let me know if any of my comments helped.

Comment: i think the error message is truncating the sql, the sql i listed is the value of the "sql" variable that is being passed to the database.

Answer (score 0):

So just reading the error message and comparing to the (working) query above:

```
Working:         INSERT INTO address_tbl (address_ln_1, address_ln_2, address_town, address_county, address_postcode) VALUES ('place', '', 'Town', 'county', 'postcode');

Error Message:  'INSERT INTO address_tbl (address_ln_1, address_ln_2, address_town, address_count'
```

You're missing some of the parameters for your Table Insert.  I'd look at why that is.

Comment: i think the error message is truncating the sql, the sql i listed is the value of the "sql" variable that is being passed to the database.